# bower.json Error ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following dependencies in my bower.json file:

```
{
"name": "aposoft-frontend",
"dependencies": {
"angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
"jquery": "~2.1.4",
"bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
"angular-i18n": "~1.4.2",
"angular-local-storage": "~0.2.2",
"angular-http-auth": "~1.2.2",
"angular-bootstrap-show-errors": "~2.3.0",
"angular-xeditable": "~0.1.9",
"pace": "~1.0.2",
"angular-mocks": "~1.4.3",
"angular-ui-validate": "~1.1.1",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.7.2",
"quick-ng-repeat": "~0.0.1",
"angular-holderjs": "~1.1.0",
"holderjs": "~2.8.2",
"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "latest"
},
"devDependencies": {}
}
```

without **"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "latest"** it works fine but with the dependency **"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "latest"** I get following ERROR if I will build my frontend:

```
**[ERROR] bower ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular**
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` in place of `latest` to install the latest version